# Wait for several db connections before starting express server?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, express, node-redis

I'm working on an Express app. At startup it connects to a Redis server and to a PostgreSQL sever. I'd like to wait for both connections to succeed before starting the express server. Now, if I were waiting on just *one* callback, I could initiate the Express server within that callback. But how to best do this when waiting on more than one async operation? I'm new to this. Is there a good idiomatic pattern for doing this sort of thing? Maybe grouping promises together or..?

Comment: I don't know about Redis server, but a new connection with PostgreSQL takes less than 100ms, hardly any point in delaying the start of an Express application. Besides, an app would access the server asynchronously, so really that logic is redundant. Have a look at [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), it does well with asynchronous access to Postgres.

Comment: In my case, both the PostgreSQL server and the Redis servers were running on machines elsewhere on the internet than the express server, so the connections were occasionally taking a bit longer than 100ms. Even if they were all on 1 server, I guess I'd still worry about accessing a DB (in the Express startup code say) that was not officially connected yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises are what you want.

You can use `.all()` on an array of promises to wait for them all to complete.  You didn't mention what Promise library you're using, but it's fairly universal.  here's the Bluebird documentation:  https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise

Comment: Thanks! I am new to the promise pattern and was not using a particular implementation (yet) but I had a hunch that promises might help. Did not know about Bluebird. So I take it that in my case there will be an array of two promises, one for the redis connection and one for the postgres connection. And Bluebird has a promisifyAll function that looks helpful.

Comment: @BobbyCircle Yes, that's correct.  All the promise libraries have some sort of "all" function that you can make a single promise out of an array of promises.

Answer (score 1):

Promises are probably the idiomatic way to solve this.  You will have to "promisify" your functions that return callbacks to turn them into something that returns and resolves promises, but then `Promise.all()` will work just fine.  I personally use Bluebird for my nodejs development and regularly promisify existing functions or whole modules that use asynchronous callbacks.

---

If you aren't otherwise using a library that can promisify non-promised functions, then you can also just use a counter to keep track of when all your callbacks are done.  This is the "older fashioned" way of doing things, but works just fine too.  Such an operation works like this:

```
function setup(fn) {
    // initialize counter to number of async operations
    var counter = 3;
    function checkDone() {
        --counter;
        if (counter <= 0) {
            fn();
        }
    }

    firstAsyncFunction(...., checkDone);
    secondAsyncFunction(...., checkDone);
    thirdAsyncFunction(...., checkDone);

}

setup(function() {
    // this will get called when all the initial async operations are done
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. The 'promisify' functions look really helpful here.